# Setting up of View frame is taking more time

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode7, frame

I have UIViewController which view frame i am setting up. It is taking almost .6sec to set up. Could anyone please tell me that how should do that, So it takes less time.

Here is my code snippet

```
    hisPanel=[[HISImageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HISImageViewController" bundle:nil];
    CGRect frame=_DeviceView.bounds;
    frame.origin.x=1;
    frame.origin.y=1;
    frame.size.height-=2;
    frame.size.width-=2;
    NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];
    hisPanel.view.frame = frame;
    NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
    Execution time = 0.6 sec
```

Comment: This might be due to heavy lifting in your controller's `viewDidLoad`. Also, the tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: I commented out all the code from viewDidLoad of my controller. But, still it's taking that much time.

Comment: As your class heirachy is unknown, we might not be able to help. Is the initialization (e.g. the first line) is taking so much time or the setting of the view's frame?

Comment: NSDate *methodStart = [NSDate date];
        hisPanel.view.frame = frame;
        NSDate *methodFinish = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodFinish timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];
        Execution time = 0.6 sec

Comment: OP, please delete that comment and edit your question.